# Is the python keyword "is" the same as the function id(), in the context of unittesting?

Tags: python, unit-testing, keyword

I have tried reading the docs but couldn't get a clear answer.

Is

```
id(a) == id(b)
```

the same as

```
a is b
```

Likewise is

```
import unittest
unittest.TestCase.assertNotEqual(id(a), id(b))
```

therefore the same as

```
import unittest
unittest.TestCase.assertIsNot(a, b)
```

Comment: @Makoto Little mention of `id` in that question or its answers... (I'd say none, but two answers *mention* it without addressing this question) That question is the olde "`is` seems to work for strings", this question is the more novel "is `is` equivalent to `id()` comparison".

Comment: @delnan:  The answer contains the fact that `is` tests for identity, and the `id()` function [returns the identity of an object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id0).  I'd say there's sufficient mention in the answer.

Comment: @Makoto Putting these two together is question and answer IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**

"id" in CPython gives you the memory address of the object referred to. The address uniquely identifies an object in the same python process.

Therefore, the meaning of

```
id(a) == id(b)
```

is *"Are the memory addresses of instance a and b the same?"* which is equivalent to
 *"Do a and b refer to the same object?"*:

```
a is b
```

From "id"'s docstring:

> id(object) -> integer
>
> Return the identity of an object.  This is guaranteed to be unique among
>   simultaneously existing objects.  (Hint: it's the object's memory address.)

Comment: How about non-CPython implementations such as PyPy?

Comment: @delnan: at least in PyPy, `id(a) == id(b) <-> a is b` [(ref)](http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cpython_differences.html#object-identity-of-primitive-values-is-and-id).

Comment: @delnan If id(a)==id(b) is true in CPython then it is true in PyPy. This is not always the case the other way around. Try: (1000000000 + 1) is (1000000000+1). The latter is always true in PyPy, but not in CPython.

Comment: Great. I didn't ask because I don't know that (I even know *why* it's like that), I asked because the *answer* could use this information.

Comment: According to the Python Language Reference at the end of section 5.9. Comparisons the 'is' operator tests for object identity. So assertIsNot(a,b) can always be replaced with assertNotEqual(id(a), id(b)). Depending on implementation internals you could get different results when it comes to value types, so avoid using 'is' when you want to compare values, as you don't know if it will work on othe implementations or event future implementations.